# A way to capture the Javascript which is changing an element's CSS property?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-devtools, dom-events, firebug

I have a div which is getting hidden/displayed by a click on another element. I can see the div's visibility CSS property changing in Firebug. The div is initialized using Microsoft Javascript library in code using:

```
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {$create.....
```

How do I get the actual Javascript which runs during run time with every click? Is there a way to intercept the js call and see what code is exactly running, like in Firebug or Chrome's Developer Tools?

(This is NOT a question on how to hide/unhide an element. I know how to do this)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know in Chrome Dev Tools what you can try to do is:

1. Find the element clicking on which is causing your div to hide.
2. Expand it's `Event Listeners` in the right bar
3. Expand the `click` event
4. Then click the source file displayed there for the click event.

It would take you to where the click event function, so you can put a break point there. This is what you're asking, right?